# Ubuntu 12.04 dropbox icon missing in tray (no working solution)

Tags: 12.04, icons, dropbox

I have the dropbox missing icon display problem.

I try solutions like "sudo apt-get install libappindicator1", removing all the package and dropbox directories, reinstalling and no icon shows up.

the dropbox daemon works and update the directory without problem.

this is strange since, I use 2 different ubuntu 12.04 installations, one show up the  dropbox icon fine and the second do not.

thanks

Comment: I have the same problem: on the same machine and same OS, for one user it works fine, for another it doesn't. I suspect it is some tray icon display problem, not necessarily related to Unity

Comment: I have the exac same problem: two machines with Ubuntu 12.04 and gnome classic, one both up to date, one of them works well, the other does not show the icon (just a single dot). It is Dropbox 3.0.4. None of the above solutions worked.

Comment: I also see "the dot" instead of an icon (Ubuntu 14.04).  It is at least possible to access the Dropbox menu by (carefully) right-clicking exactly one pixel to-the-left-of or above the dot (depending on your panel orientation).  Has this been reported to dropbox? (anyone have a link?)

Answer (score 8):

Same problem for me... I solved by typing in a terminal:

```
dropbox stop
dropbox start
```

I have not rebooted the pc yet so I don't know if this solution works also after rebooting but for now I have the icon working. If you want type also:

```
dropbox autostart y
```

Answer (score 7):

I had this Problem and none of the above worked for me. However the solution was simple. Im using the gnome classic environment,hold Alt + WinKey whilst you  right click on panel.select Add to panel and add NOTIFICATION AREA. Voilla Dropbox Icon appears 
Hope this can help someone

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure everything is installed correctly, you should run in a terminal:

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist
```

The output will be a list, looking like:

```
['item1', 'item2']
```

Dropbox will probably not be in it. Edit the list in (for example) gedit, adding 'dropbox' to the list, and run in a terminal:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Panel systray-whitelist "['item1', 'item2', 'dropbox']"
```

After log out / log in, the Dropbox icon should be in the tray again.

Comment: This did not work on 12.04 with dual monitors.  An icon showed up on one monitor but it did not look or function correctly.

Comment: @Antonios You describe another problem, which probably has nothing to do with op's problem. I suggest  you ask another question instead of downvoting a correct answer to this question.

Comment: your solution makes an icon show up but it does not solve the op's problem.  The icon that shows up is not the same as the icon that shows up when the dropbox daemon is stopped and restarted. It does not function the same either.

Comment: Not sure why it didnt work for others but it did for me and I didnt need to logout, just adding 'dropbox' to the whitelist while it was stopped (via cli 'dropbox stop') and then running dropbox start brought the tray icon back for me.

Comment: @Maks If you stop and restart the daemon the icon shows up correctly even if you do not add 'dropbox' to the whitelist

Comment: @Antonios thats quite possible, but it is the same icon I have had all along and it does function the same way it always has - for me anyway - it has the drop down menu, showing the sync status, recently changed files, etc